# X.509 RSA Encryption/Decryption iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption, rsa, x509

I need to implement encryption / decryption using a X.509 RSA public/private key pair.

So far, I have something which I think will work for encryption, but I have no way of decrypting to check. Everything I try has issues reading the private key.

### Generating the key pairs (returns a `.der` and a `.pem`)

```
openssl req -x509 -out public_key.der -outform der -new -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout private_key.pem -days 3650
```

### Encryption (Not sure if this works, but looks like it does)

```
+ (NSData *) RSAEncryptData:(NSData *)content {
    SecKeyRef publicKey;
    SecCertificateRef certificate;
    SecPolicyRef policy;
    SecTrustRef trust;
    size_t maxPlainLen;

    NSString *publicKeyPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"public_key" ofType:@"der"];
    NSData *base64KeyData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:publicKeyPath];

    certificate = SecCertificateCreateWithData(kCFAllocatorDefault, ( __bridge CFDataRef) base64KeyData);
    if (certificate == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Can not read certificate from data");
        return nil;
    }

    policy = SecPolicyCreateBasicX509();
    OSStatus returnCode = SecTrustCreateWithCertificates(certificate, policy, &trust);
    if (returnCode != 0) {
        NSLog(@"SecTrustCreateWithCertificates fail. Error Code: %d", (int)returnCode);
        return nil;
    }

    SecTrustResultType trustResultType;
    returnCode = SecTrustEvaluate(trust, &trustResultType);
    if (returnCode != 0) {
        return nil;
    }

    publicKey = SecTrustCopyPublicKey(trust);
    if (publicKey == nil) {
        NSLog(@"SecTrustCopyPublicKey fail");
        return nil;
    }

    maxPlainLen = SecKeyGetBlockSize(publicKey) - 12;


    size_t plainLen = [content length];
    if (plainLen > maxPlainLen) {
        NSLog(@"content(%ld) is too long, must < %ld", plainLen, maxPlainLen);
        return nil;
    }

    void *plain = malloc(plainLen);
    [content getBytes:plain
               length:plainLen];

    size_t cipherLen = 128; // currently RSA key length is set to 128 bytes
    void *cipher = malloc(cipherLen);

    OSStatus encryptReturnCode = SecKeyEncrypt(publicKey, kSecPaddingPKCS1, plain,
                                        plainLen, cipher, &cipherLen);

    NSData *result = nil;
    if (encryptReturnCode != 0) {
        NSLog(@"SecKeyEncrypt fail. Error Code: %d", (int)returnCode);
    }
    else {
        result = [NSData dataWithBytes:cipher
                                length:cipherLen];
    }

    free(plain);
    free(cipher);

    return result;
}
```

### Decryption

I have tried using OpenSSL's `PEM_read_X509` also `PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey`, but both fail to read the cert. I have not even gotten past that. If I could do this without having a dependency on the OpenSSL library, that would be even better.

```
+(void)readTest{
    FILE *fp;
    X509 *x;
    NSString *path =[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"private_key" ofType:@"pem"];
    fp=fopen([path UTF8String],"r");

    x=NULL;
    PEM_read_X509(fp,&x,NULL,NULL); // I have also tried PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey

    if (x == NULL) {
        NSLog(@"Cant Read File"); // This ALWAYS fires
    }

    fclose(fp);
    X509_free(x);
}
```

If someone could help me out with encryption/decryption using X.509 RSA pairs, I'd appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: btw, certificates expire after a period of time and you need to keep maintaining it, how will you maintain when you push this app ?

Comment: the real app is only encrypting messages to a provider using their public key, which is retrieved over the network. Decryption is done on the server-side in real-world use.

Comment: i guess the certificates are not valid since they are self-signed, looks like you need to figure out a way to make it trusted

Comment: yeah of course, the public key still needs a certificate according to your implementation, you need to come up with some way to renew your certificate, moreover you should think of a way to get a certificate, sign it with some company who convert them into a trusted one and then send it on time

Comment: There has to be a way to do this without buying a CA-trusted key pair? The key-pair validation and trust is not my responsibility in this use case.

Comment: one way is to create the prime using some technique, ensure some service send you the public key in pkcs1 padding format, create a seckeyref and then do encryption

Comment: i would recommend you to go through the example @ mac os samples for this, using ccrypt, lemme get you the link

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/CryptoCompatibility/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Why are you using the Security framework methods for encryption, but OpenSSL for decryption?

Comment: Are you running this from inside a unit test? If you run this from the command line, does it show your private key to be valid? openssl rsa -in private_key.pem -check

Comment: @quellish For some reason Security.framework had issues reading my private key? I would much rather use SecKeyDecrypt if possible.

Comment: @quellish running that line prints my private key to the console, it looks valid to me.

Comment: And the path being passed to fopen is correct, and fp is not NULL or a garbage pointer?

Comment: And your private key doesn't have a password?

Comment: Correct, I removed it using: openssl rsa -in private_key.pem -out newkey.pem

Comment: @quellish Can you send me a snippet of what you are testing with using SecKeyDecrypt()? Also are you using the command at the top or a different one to generate your key pair?

Comment: If you use a private key that DOES have a password, does it work?

Comment: The Security framework does not appear to be the problem, it's either the key or something about the environment you're running it in. I'm not able to replicate what you're seeing using your code and steps, though I was using a password.

Comment: The only issue I see with your encryption is `cipherLen` should be a value that is the block size times the size of the data type. i.e. `SecKeyGetBlockSize(publicKey) * sizeof(uint8_t)` . Your ciphertext may be getting truncated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Where you are stuck

It seems your private key is encrypted (openssl asked you for a password on the command line), yet you do not decrypt it when you try to open it. Besides, private_key.pem is an RSA key, not a certificate, so you should use PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey.

The following decoding code should work:

```
int pass_cb(char *buf, int size, int rwflag, void* password) {
    snprintf(buf, size, "%s", (char*) password);
    return strlen(buf);
}

+(void)readTest{
    FILE *fp;
    RSA *x;
    NSString *path =[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"private_key" ofType:@"pem"];
    fp=fopen([path UTF8String],"r");

    x = PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey(fp,&x,pass_cb,"key password");

    if (x == NULL) {
        NSLog(@"Cant Read File"); // This ALWAYS fires
    }

    fclose(fp);
    X509_free(x);
}
```

Alternatively, you could generate a non-encrypted key. Pass `-nodes` to openssl when creating the keys and the certificate.

Please note that you might need to make sure OpenSSL is properly initialized with:

```
SSL_library_init();
OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
```

Besides, OpenSSL generates error messages that could help you through development. You load the error strings with:

```
SSL_load_error_strings();
```

And you could call:

```
ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
```

#### RSA encryption and decryption on iOS

OpenSSL is not the only solution as Security framework on iOS contains everything you need. I guess you turned to OpenSSL because you did not know how to convert your private key file to valid parameters for SecKeyDecrypt.

The trick is to produce a PKCS#12 file and to call `SecPKCS12Import`.

You can produce this file with OpenSSL:

```
openssl x509 -inform der -outform pem -in public_key.der -out public_key.pem
openssl pkcs12 -export -in public_key.pem -inkey private_key.pem -out private_key.p12
```

This will ask you for an export password. This password should be passed to SecPKCS12Import (`"key password"` below).

```
NSString *privateKeyPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"private_key" ofType:@"p12"];
NSData *pkcs12key = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:privateKeyPath];
NSDictionary* options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"key password", kSecImportExportPassphrase, nil];
CFArrayRef              importedItems = NULL;
OSStatus returnCode = SecPKCS12Import(
                      (__bridge CFDataRef) pkcs12key,
                      (__bridge CFDictionaryRef) options,
                      &importedItems
                      );
```

`importedItems` is an array containing all imported PKCS12 items, and basically, the "identity" (private key + certificate).

```
NSDictionary* item = (NSDictionary*) CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(importedItems, 0);
SecIdentityRef  identity = (__bridge SecIdentityRef) [item objectForKey:(__bridge NSString *) kSecImportItemIdentity];
SecKeyRef privateKeyRef;
SecIdentityCopyPrivateKey(identity, &privateKeyRef);
```

Then you can use privateKeyRef to perform the decryption with `SecKeyDecrypt`. To match your encryption routine:

```
size_t cipherLen = [content length];
void *cipher = malloc(cipherLen);
[content getBytes:cipher length:cipherLen];
size_t plainLen = SecKeyGetBlockSize(privateKeyRef) - 12;
void *plain = malloc(plainLen);

OSStatus decryptReturnCode = SecKeyDecrypt(privateKeyRef, kSecPaddingPKCS1, cipher, cipherLen, plain, &plainLen);
```

Comment: This is beautiful. I see where my problem was - Thanks a lot.