# Creating x509 certificates programmatically in Objective-C using the CommonCrypto framework

Tags: java, objective-c, security, rsa, x509

I use [this function](https://gist.github.com/tvd12/9a446c6f1ce976681f34bde47b3e4503) to generate RSA public key

And I get a public key

```
ET0VgP//HQGAIwEAAQAAAKgFJ4f/fwAA6BqkBQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAACAhpAUBAAAA
mSZaEAAAABDhNFoQAAAAcAUAAAAAAAAACQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
UHJpbnROYW1lAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABQAQDaMFAQAAAMATowUBAAAA
oKihBQEAAAABAAAAAAAAACJTY0Zpcm13YXJlVmVyc2lvbgAFAQAAAAUAAAAAAAAA
dTFaEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA0AogUBAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAQGKMFAQAAAKD8ogUBAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAATMVoQAAAAoA==
```

But when I use the public key to encrypte data in java I get an error

```java
Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: invalid key format
    at sun.security.x509.X509Key.decode(X509Key.java:387)
    at sun.security.x509.X509Key.decode(X509Key.java:402)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPublicKeyImpl.<init>(RSAPublicKeyImpl.java:122)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.generatePublic(RSAKeyFactory.java:331)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePublic(RSAKeyFactory.java:236)
```

So how can I create X.509 cer in ObjectiveC?

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that RSA is a signature algorithm and X.509 is a standard for the format and contents of certificates. So to go to the core of the issue: according to me what you generate from ObjC is just the RSA key (not in X.509 format). Actually in ObjC it is not straightforward to generate X.509 format.

Something that will be very helpful if you have an understanding of Swift would be to check the implementation of `dataByPrependingX509Header` in this file: https://github.com/henrinormak/Heimdall/blob/master/Heimdall/Heimdall.swift (a library that is exactly related RSA and similar security topics). Please write back if you need support in the exact implementation. Are you able to use Swift code in your project and what about 3rd party libraries?

**EDIT**:
I know this is more of a suggestion than an answer, but the encryption part from this question will help you, as once you have the RSA, you only need to wrap it with the X.509 wrapper: [X.509 RSA Encryption/Decryption iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23615932/x-509-rsa-encryption-decryption-ios)

Comment: thank you, I've already use openssl (https://github.com/youngmonkeys/ezyfox-server-cpp-client/blob/codec/src/codec/EzyEncryption.cpp), but I don't want to use 3rd part

Comment: @dungtavan, then maybe you could just implement the function that wraps the RSA with X.509 yourself. Another proposal, since you are using openssl - you could directly convert it to X.509 using openssl: https://gist.github.com/diorahman/274e667b0bb99d854806